# How can we update and Upload content to Blob in Azure using C#

Tags: upload, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I  am putting the question and also the answer hoping to benefit others. You need to install Azure.Storage.Blobs pacakage

Answer (score 0):

See the code below

//  A content uploader class
// install package Azure.Storage.Blobs

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AnAzureFunctionApp
{
    public class ContentUploader
    {
        public async Task UploadContentsToBlob(string azureStorageAccountConnectionString,
            string storageContainerName, string blobFileName)
        {
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(azureStorageAccountConnectionString);

            // Create the container and return a container client object
            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(storageContainerName);
            await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobFileName);

            await AddBlobContents(blobClient);
        }

        private async Task AddBlobContents(BlockBlobClient blobClient)
        {
            await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Download the blob's contents if it exist and save it to a memory file
            if (blobClient.Exists())
            {
                var blobDownloadInfo = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
                await blobDownloadInfo.Value.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            }

            byte[] timeBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Process is Run at " + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
            await memoryStream.WriteAsync(timeBytes, 0, timeBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            //Upload the contents
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you downloading the blob and overwriting its contents and uploading it? You really don't have to do that. You could simply perform an upload operation with new contents and the blob's contents will be modified.